# Mostrar Query en Ventana Modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo una duda con AJAX & PHP.

Tengo una tabla de clientes y me gustaria que en una ventana modal bootstrap me mostrara una consulta mysql en funcion al cliente que yo presione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que al presionar INFO me muestre la Modal con una consulta en funcion al row que he presionado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando Ajax para hacer las consultas pero no se porque no me muestra nada :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CONSULTA:`SELECT hist_id, pay_id, user_uid, pay_amount, pay_totalint, pay_totalpay, pay_amountrest, hist_date FROM payments_history WHERE hist_id='".$_POST['id']."' ORDER BY hist_date DESC`

AJAX:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_info', function(){

    var id= $(this).data("id8");

        $.ajax({
            url:"clientsm.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                fetch_data2();
            }
        });


});
```

PD: estoy en la pagina clientesm.php

Ayuda porfavor, hice esta pregunta hace como un mes y no me han respondido.

PAGINA: ClIENTSM.PHP

```
   <?php
   session_start();  

    include_once 'header.php';
    include_once 'includes/dbc.inc.php';

    /*Para no escribir tantos ECHO se crea la variable OUPUT*/
    $output = '';

    $username='';

    /*Cargo mi tabla con los valores de la tabla Clientes*/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";

    /*almaceno el resultado de mi query*/
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $output .= '
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <h2>Clientes</h2><br>

   /*Fly este formulario lo agregue porque pensaba que si la ancla 
   <a> donde presiono mi INFO no estaba dentro de un formulario no 
    recibiria la instruccion*/
      <form action="clientsm.php" method="GET">

       <div class="container table-responsive" >                    
          <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                    <tr>  
                       <th >Id</th>  
                       <th >First Name</th>  
                       <th >Last Name</th>
                       <th >Username</th>  
                       <th >Password</th>  
                       <th >Phone Number</th>
                       <th >Email</th>   

                    </tr>
              </thead>';

             /*Si el resultado en numero de registros de mi query SQL  
             es mayor a 0 significa que hay datos a cargar en la 
              tabla*/  
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
             {  
             /*Por cada registro de mi tabla Clientes que me los vaya 
             agregando a la tabla y los almaceno en la variable ROW*/
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
             {       

             $output .='
              <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["user_id"].'</td> 

                        <td class="user_first" data- 
                    id1="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                   contenteditable>'.$row["user_first"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_last" data- 
                    id2="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                    contenteditable>'.$row["user_last"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_uid" data- 
                    id3="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                    contenteditable>'.$row["user_uid"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_pwd" data- 
                     id4="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                     contenteditable>'.$row["user_pwd"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_phone" data- 
                       id5="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                       contenteditable>'.$row["user_phone"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_email" data- 
                        id6="'.$row["user_id"].'" 
                         contenteditable>'.$row["user_email"].'</td>

                        <td>
                        <button type="button" name="btn_delete2" 
                        id="btn_delete2" data- 
                         id7="'.$row["user_id"].'" class="btn btn-xs 
                         btn-danger btn_delete2">DELETE
                        </button>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data- 
                      id8="'.$row["user_id"].'" class="btn_info" data- 
                      target="#paymentshist" id="trigger-btn">INFO
                        </a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>';
                     }

                     $output .= '  
                    <tr>  
                        <td></td>

                        <td id="user_first" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_last" contenteditable></td>
                        <td id="user_uid" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_pwd" contenteditable></td>
                        <td id="user_phone" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_email" contenteditable></td>

                        <td>
                        <button type="button" name="btn_add2" 
                        id="btn_add2" class="btn btn-xs btn- 
                        success">ADD
                        </button>
                        </td>  
                    </tr>';
                    }
                    /*Si el numero de registros de mi query SQL es 
                     menor o igual a 0 entonces me muestra lo 
                     siguiente*/  
                     else  
                     {

                    $output .= '
                      <tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">NO hay registros para 
                         Mostrar
                          </td>  
                      </tr>';  
                      }  
                    $output .= '
                </table>  
                 </div>
                 </form>';

                echo $output;


                ?>

                <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">


                   <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen" 
                   id="paymentshist" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
                   labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data- 
                   dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria- 
                   hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Historial 
                  de Pagos</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">

                  <?php

                   /*Para no escribir tantos ECHO se crea la variable 
                   OUPUT*/
                  $output = '';



                  $querypaymentshist="SELECT hist_id, pay_id, 
                  user_uid, pay_amount, pay_totalint, pay_totalpay, 
                   pay_amountrest, hist_date FROM payments_history 
                   WHERE hist_id='".$_POST['id']."' ORDER BY hist_date 
                    DESC";

                  /*almaceno el resultado de mi query*/
                  $resultpamentshist = mysqli_query($conn, 
                  $querypaymentshist);


                  $output .= '
                   <br>

                   <div class="container table-responsive">                    
                   <table class="table table-hover">
                   <thead>
                    <tr>  
                       <th >Id</th>  
                       <th >Pay_Id</th>  
                       <th >Usuario</th>
                       <th >Ingreso</th>  
                       <th >Intereses</th>  
                       <th >Abonado</th>
                       <th >Capital</th>
                       <th >Fecha</th>  

                    </tr>
                    </thead>';

                  /*Si el resultado en numero de registros de mi query 
                querypaymentshist  es mayor a 0 significa que hay 
               datos a cargar en la tabla*/  
               if(mysqli_num_rows($resultpamentshist) > 0)  
               {  
                  /*Por cada registro de mi tabla Payments que me los 
                  vaya agregando a la tabla y los almaceno en la 
                 variable ROWph*/
                 while($rowph = 
                  mysqli_fetch_array($resultpamentshist))  
                    {       

                 $output .='
              <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$rowph["hist_id"].'</td> 

                        <td class="pay_id" data- 
                        id1="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                        contenteditable>'.$rowph["pay_id"].'</td>

                        <td class="user_uid" data- 
                        id2="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                         contenteditable>'.$rowph["user_uid"].'</td>

                        <td class="pay_amount" data- 
                        id3="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                        contenteditable>'.$rowph["pay_amount"].'</td>

                        <td class="pay_totalint" data- 
                         id4="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                       contenteditable>'.$rowph["pay_totalint"].'</td>

                        <td class="pay_totalpay" data- 
                         id5="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                      contenteditable>'.$rowph["pay_totalpay"].'</td>

                        <td class="pay_amountrest" data- 
                       id6="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                     contenteditable>'.$rowph["pay_amountrest"].'</td>

                        <td class="hist_date" data- 
                      id7="'.$rowph["hist_id"].'" 
                     contenteditable>'.$rowph["hist_date"].'</td>

                    </tr>
                   </tbody>';
                  }
                    }
                   /*Si el numero de registros de mi query 
                   resultpamentshist es menor o igual a 0 entonces me 
                   muestra lo siguiente*/  
                    else  
                     {

                      $output .= '
                      <tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">NO hay registros para 
                          Mostrar
                          </td>  
                      </tr>';  
                        }  
                       $output .= '
                     </table>  
                     </div>';

                    echo $output;



                       ?>

                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                       data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                        </div>

                       <?php
                       include_once 'footer.php'; 
                        ?>
```

Comment: Que hace fetch_data2()? no le pasa ningún parámetro... Podrías mostrarnos por consola  el valor de `data` dentro del `success` ?

Comment: Me muestra Simplemente 

UNDEFINED. clientsm.php:404 

En esa linea esta el console.log(fetch_data2());

cuando le paso el console.log(data);
Me muestra todo lo que tengo en la pagina clientsm.php incluyendo los divs, ; , etc..

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo amigo, si crees que haya otra manera de hacer lo que quiero tambien lo agradeceria :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CONSULTA:**

La consulta debería estar filtrada por usuario:

```
SELECT hist_id, pay_id, user_uid, pay_amount, pay_totalint, pay_totalpay, pay_amountrest, hist_date
  FROM payments_history WHERE user_uid='".$_POST['id']."' 
 ORDER BY hist_date DESC
```

**AJAX:**

El `dataType` debería ser "html".

> The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess
>   (xml, json, script, text, html).

Fuente :http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/

fetch_data2() sigo sin saber que hace, lo elimino y en su lugar inyecto el html en la ventana modal (me inventaré el id de la ventana modal porque no indicas nada sobre ella):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_info', function(){

var id= $(this).data("id8");

    $.ajax({
        url:"clientsm_ajax.php",
        method:"GET",
        data:{id:id},
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data){
            $('#mi_modal').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

(edito)
<del>Como no muestras lo que hace `clientsm.php` yo asumo que genera el html válido de una `<table>` con los datos de pago de un usuario.</del>

El problema comienza al llamar desde el ajax al mismo script que genera la página, evita esto porque solo hace complicarte el código.

Te he separado el script inicial en dos, **cortando** entre las la linea 155 y 254 quedaría:

**CLIENTSM.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'header.php';
include_once 'includes/dbc.inc.php';

/* Para no escribir tantos ECHO se crea la variable OUPUT */
$output = '';

$username = '';

/* Cargo mi tabla con los valores de la tabla Clientes */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";

/* almaceno el resultado de mi query */
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$output .= '
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <h2>Clientes</h2><br>

   /*Fly este formulario lo agregue porque pensaba que si la ancla 
   <a> donde presiono mi INFO no estaba dentro de un formulario no 
    recibiria la instruccion*/
      <form action="clientsm.php" method="GET">

       <div class="container table-responsive" >                    
          <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                    <tr>  
                       <th >Id</th>  
                       <th >First Name</th>  
                       <th >Last Name</th>
                       <th >Username</th>  
                       <th >Password</th>  
                       <th >Phone Number</th>
                       <th >Email</th>   

                    </tr>
              </thead>';

/* Si el resultado en numero de registros de mi query SQL  
  es mayor a 0 significa que hay datos a cargar en la
  tabla */
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    /* Por cada registro de mi tabla Clientes que me los vaya 
      agregando a la tabla y los almaceno en la variable ROW */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $output .= '
              <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $row["user_id"] . '</td> 

                        <td class="user_first" data- 
                    id1="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                   contenteditable>' . $row["user_first"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_last" data- 
                    id2="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                    contenteditable>' . $row["user_last"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_uid" data- 
                    id3="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                    contenteditable>' . $row["user_uid"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_pwd" data- 
                     id4="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                     contenteditable>' . $row["user_pwd"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_phone" data- 
                       id5="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                       contenteditable>' . $row["user_phone"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_email" data- 
                        id6="' . $row["user_id"] . '" 
                         contenteditable>' . $row["user_email"] . '</td>

                        <td>
                        <button type="button" name="btn_delete2" 
                        id="btn_delete2" data- 
                         id7="' . $row["user_id"] . '" class="btn btn-xs 
                         btn-danger btn_delete2">DELETE
                        </button>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data- 
                      id8="' . $row["user_id"] . '" class="btn_info" data- 
                      target="#paymentshist" id="trigger-btn">INFO
                        </a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>';
    }

    $output .= '  
                    <tr>  
                        <td></td>

                        <td id="user_first" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_last" contenteditable></td>
                        <td id="user_uid" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_pwd" contenteditable></td>
                        <td id="user_phone" contenteditable></td>  
                        <td id="user_email" contenteditable></td>

                        <td>
                        <button type="button" name="btn_add2" 
                        id="btn_add2" class="btn btn-xs btn- 
                        success">ADD
                        </button>
                        </td>  
                    </tr>';
}
/* Si el numero de registros de mi query SQL es 
  menor o igual a 0 entonces me muestra lo
  siguiente */ else {

    $output .= '
                      <tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">NO hay registros para 
                         Mostrar
                          </td>  
                      </tr>';
}
$output .= '
                </table>  
                 </div>
                 </form>';

echo $output;
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">


        <div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen" 
             id="paymentshist" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
             labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data- 
                                dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria- 
                                 hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Historial 
                            de Pagos</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="mi_modal">
                        Hola!!! soy una ventana flotante, aqui puedo poner cualquier
                        texto, porque estoy oculta, si cuando me vuelva visible
                        puedes leer este texto significará que el ajax a fallado.

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        include_once 'footer.php';
        ?>
```

Como puedes ver la ventana flotante la genero vacía (bueno, casi vacía) porque no tiene sentido meter datos, dependerá de lo que pulse el usuario.

> Añadí `id="mi_modal"` al div del cuerpo de la modal porque es donde se
>   insertará la respuesta del ajax.

El nuevo fichero llevará la parte que genera la tabla de resultados, la que se insertará en la ventana modal, eso y solo eso, va a ser el fichero que se llame desde el ajax y debe responder a los parámetros enviados (en este caso solo `id`,por cierto, modifiqué el javascript anterior para hacerlo coincidir con este fichero), sería:

**CLIENTSM_AJAX.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'includes/dbc.inc.php';
/* Para no escribir tantos ECHO se crea la variable 
  OUPUT */
$output = '';



$querypaymentshist = "SELECT hist_id, pay_id, 
                  user_uid, pay_amount, pay_totalint, pay_totalpay, 
                   pay_amountrest, hist_date FROM payments_history 
                   WHERE user_uid='" . intval($_GET['id']) . "' ORDER BY hist_date 
                    DESC";

/* almaceno el resultado de mi query */
$resultpamentshist = mysqli_query($conn, $querypaymentshist);


$output .= '
                   <br>

                   <div class="container table-responsive">                    
                   <table class="table table-hover">
                   <thead>
                    <tr>  
                       <th >Id</th>  
                       <th >Pay_Id</th>  
                       <th >Usuario</th>
                       <th >Ingreso</th>  
                       <th >Intereses</th>  
                       <th >Abonado</th>
                       <th >Capital</th>
                       <th >Fecha</th>  

                    </tr>
                    </thead>';

/* Si el resultado en numero de registros de mi query 
  querypaymentshist  es mayor a 0 significa que hay
  datos a cargar en la tabla */
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultpamentshist) > 0) {
    /* Por cada registro de mi tabla Payments que me los 
      vaya agregando a la tabla y los almaceno en la
      variable ROWph */
    while ($rowph = mysqli_fetch_array($resultpamentshist)) {

        $output .= '
              <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '</td> 

                        <td class="pay_id" data- 
                        id1="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                        contenteditable>' . $rowph["pay_id"] . '</td>

                        <td class="user_uid" data- 
                        id2="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                         contenteditable>' . $rowph["user_uid"] . '</td>

                        <td class="pay_amount" data- 
                        id3="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                        contenteditable>' . $rowph["pay_amount"] . '</td>

                        <td class="pay_totalint" data- 
                         id4="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                       contenteditable>' . $rowph["pay_totalint"] . '</td>

                        <td class="pay_totalpay" data- 
                         id5="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                      contenteditable>' . $rowph["pay_totalpay"] . '</td>

                        <td class="pay_amountrest" data- 
                       id6="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                     contenteditable>' . $rowph["pay_amountrest"] . '</td>

                        <td class="hist_date" data- 
                      id7="' . $rowph["hist_id"] . '" 
                     contenteditable>' . $rowph["hist_date"] . '</td>

                    </tr>
                   </tbody>';
    }
}
/* Si el numero de registros de mi query 
  resultpamentshist es menor o igual a 0 entonces me
  muestra lo siguiente */ else {

    $output .= '
                      <tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">NO hay registros para 
                          Mostrar
                          </td>  
                      </tr>';
}
$output .= '
                     </table>  
                     </div>';

echo $output;
?>
```

El script debe ser completamente funcional, debe incluir lo necesario para la conexión a base de datos, así como iniciar sesion si vas a hacer uso de alguna variable `$_SESSION`.

La consulta la modifique respecto a la original, como ya comenté, para buscar filtrando por id del cliente, que es el parámetro que me envía el ajax.

Como puedes ver lo tenías todo ya casi funcional,solo faltaron un par de detalles.

Para facilitar la depuración y mantener el estándar, deberías hacer las peticiones de información por `GET`, así podrás probar el ajax directamente en el navegador y verificar su funcionamiento.

Comment: Fly muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por tu respuesta. hice los cambios que me has sugerido y a la hora de presionar INFO se me despliega una ventana modal pero con la misma tabla que tengo de clientes.

En la pagina clientsm.php tengo la tabla de clientes, y lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar un ROW en este caso desde la etiqueta <a> INFO me muestre un modal con un historial de pago en base a ese cliente...

PD: el historial de pago no se hace en base a un int sino que se hace en base a un user_uid un varchar.

hay forma de obtenerlo? hay algo que estoy haciendo muy mal?
Saludos.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta y agregare la pagina clientsm.php completa... de verdad que gracias por tu tiempo llevo casi 2 meses con este problema.

Comment: ya edité mi respuesta en base a la información adicional. Ahora que leo lo del `user_id` decirte que es igual que el id que envío en el ajax, da igual el nombre que le demos al enviarlo, lo importante es que el script lo lea y lo use correctamente. Revisé el código y parece correcto, debería funcionar.

Comment: Fly muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo, voy a probarlo <3 os lo agradezco enormemente. <3

Answer (score 1):

Seria mejor que separes en 3 archivos diferentes y hacer la tabla con `JQuery` es decir `pagina.php`, `script.js` y `consulta.php`

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_info', function(){
    var id= $(this).data("id8");
        $.ajax({
            url:"clientsm.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                var t = $('#tableModal').DataTable(); 
                t.row.add( [
                        data[0],
                        data[1],
                        data[2],
                        data[3],
                        data[4]'
                    ] ).draw( false );
            }
        });
});
```

```css
//clientsm.php
$id=$_POST["id"]
//db_conn=> configuracion de DB
$sql = "SELECT * from ***** WHERE id";        
$db_conn = conecta();
$result = $db_conn->query ($sql) or die ("Fallo en la consulta"); 
$d = array();
while ($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $d[]=$r;
}
print( json_encode($d));
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <!-- todo de la primera tabla -->
</table>

<div id="modal">
  <table id="tableModal">
    <!-- todo de la llenado desde ajax -->
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Puedes no usar el script de DATATABLE , Pero la idea es esa  -->
```

**El datetype que recive el ajax debe ser json**,
en caso de no usar `DATATABLE` y usar otro formato para tu tabla la idea es la misma,
**los datos desde ajax no ejecutanto PHP**
`Me faltó el FOR para recorrer el JSON`